# Call same $http function with different parameters after first is finished, using Factory in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`myData` is generated in `myFactory`, and the following code works if `myData` is generated from a single `myHttp.GetGroupMember` function.

However, it is not working with multiple `GetGroupMember` calls as they execute "at the same time", and `dataContainer` gets initialized from `createMyData` call.

How can I call second `GetGroupMember` after first `GetGroupMember` is "finished"?

```
var myFactory = function (myHttp) {

    var myData = [];
    var dataContainer = [];
    var numProgress;

    var onSuccess = function(data_member) {
        myData.push(data_member);
        numProgress++;
        loadMember(dataContainer); // if member is succefully loaded, load next member
        // if numProgress == data_member.length, call next GetGroupMember() here?
    }

    var loadMember = function(data_group) {
        if (numProgress < data_group.length) {
            myHttp.getMemberDetails(data_group.division, data_group.members[numProgress]).then(onSuccess, onError);
        }
    }

    var createMyData = function(response) {
        dataContainer = response; // coded as shown to call loadMember() iteratively
        loadMember(dataContainer);
    }

    var getMyData = function(init) {
        myHttp.getGroupMember("Division1", "Group_Foo").success(createMyData); // getGroupMember_1
        // how to call getGroupMember_2 after getGroupMember "finished"?
        myHttp.getGroupMember("Division2", "Group_Bar").success(createMyData); // getGroupMember_2

        return myData;
    }
}

var myControl = function($scope, myFactory) {

    $scope.myData = myFactory.getMyData();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing in the world:

```
myHttp.getGroupMember("Division1", "Group_Foo")
.success(createMyData)
.then(function() {
     return myHttp.getGroupMember("Division2", "Group_Bar")
}).success(createMyData);
```

Read up on [promises](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/).